# Objective C - Inserting string in an NSAttributedString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I have an `NSAttributedString`, I need to insert some text in the middle of the text in my attributedString, how can i do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
NSAttributedString *someAttrString = ...; // the original string you want to modify
NSAttributedString *someOtherAttrString = ...; // the text you want to insert
NSUInteger whereItGoes = ...; // where you want to insert the string

NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = [someAttrString mutableCopy];
if (mutableString) {
    [mutableString insertAttributedString: someOtherAttrString atIndex: whereItGoes];
    // mutableString now contains the modified data; it's up to you
    // how it gets used in your app.

    [mutableString release];
}
```